# Matrix is printing wrong dimensions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm reading in a column from a dataframe named 'OneHot'. Each row of this column has a value of either [1,0] or [0,1]. I am trying to store these values into a variable so I can use it in a neural network.

Problem:
When I read in the values into a variable it stores as (792824, 1) instead of (792824, 2). 792824 is the amount of rows in the dataframe. I have tried reshape and that did not work.

Here is the code I have:

```
    input_matrix = np.matrix(df['VectorTweet'].values.tolist())
​
In [157]:

    input_matrix = np.transpose(input_matrix)
    x_inputs = input_matrix.shape
    print x_inputs
(792824, 1)

In [160]:

    output_matrix = np.matrix(df['OneHot'].values.tolist())
    y_inputs = np.transpose(output_matrix)
    print y_outputs.shape
​
(792824, 1)

    print y_outputs[1]

[['[1, 0]']]
```

attached is a snippet of my dataframe [Example of my dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXCUe.png).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like each entry in `OneHot` is a string representation of a list.  That's why you're only getting one column in your transpose - you've made a single-element list of a string of a list of integers.  You can convert strings of lists to actual lists with `ast.literal_eval()`:

```
# OneHot as string of list of ints
strOneHot = pd.Series(['[0,1]','[1,0]'])

print(strOneHot.values)
# ['[0,1]' '[1,0]']

import ast
print(strOneHot.apply(ast.literal_eval).values)
# [[0, 1] [1, 0]]
```

FWIW, you can take the transpose of a Pandas series with `.T`, if that's useful here:

```
strOneHot.apply(ast.literal_eval).T
```

Output:

```
0    [0, 1]
1    [1, 0]
dtype: object
```